# How to optimize FFMPEG/ Editing video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have the next commands for editing video but all the process take a long time. But with the same quality of the original video.

```
//First cut original video
exec("ffmpeg -i $video_path_main -ss $first_time1 -t $first_time2 -s 476x268 -r 10 -b 2000k -r 30 -g 100 -ar 22050 -ab 48000 -ac 1 -strict -2 $name_first");
exec("ffmpeg -i $video_path_main -ss $second_time1 -t $second_time2 -s 476x268 -r 10 -b 2000k -r 30 -g 100 -ar 22050 -ab 48000 -ac 1 -strict -2 $name_second");

$name_edit_second = uniqid() . '.mp4'; //Then editing the second video
exec("ffmpeg -i $name_second -s 476x268 -r 10 -b 2000k -r 30 -g 100 -ar 22050 -ab 48000 -ac 1 -strict -2 -vf movie='" . $image_name . " [watermark]; [in] [watermark] overlay=308:43"."' $name_edit_second");

//Then merge video file mp4 with Mencoder
$name_total_1 = uniqid() . '.mp4';
exec("mencoder -oac pcm -ovc xvid -vf scale -xvidencopts bitrate=460 -o $name_total_1 ".$name_first.' '.$name_edit_second);

//Then convert the video to 3 formats that is necessary in my Player.
$name_total = uniqid();

//Of MP4 a FLV
exec("ffmpeg -i $name_partial -f flv -s 476x268 -r 10 -b 2000k -r 30 -g 100 -ar 22050 -ab 48000 -ac 1 $name_total.flv");

//Of MP4-Mencoder a MP4-FFMPEG
exec("ffmpeg -i $name_partial -s 476x268 -r 10 -b 2000k -r 30 -g 100 -ar 22050 -ab 48000 -ac 1 -strict -2 $name_total.mp4"));

//Of MP4 a WEBM
exec("ffmpeg -i $name_partial -acodec libvorbis -s 476x268 -r 10 -b 2000k -r 30 -g 100 -ar 22050 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -f webm $name_total.webm");
```

I don't know if some of parameters take much time for all the process. Or if one of this command take much time.

Note: Some videos have more than 2 parts of their original videos.

---

### UPDATE

Maybe the parameter `-theards 1` help me in NO take a lot of resources of the CPU. Also, I need to optimize the re-encoding because with only 8 users take the 100% of resources.

I run FFMPEG in a other server that return the video edited to other server where stay my application.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What are you doing, exactly? It looks like you are making a few segments from a video, adding an image watermark, concatenating these videos, and then re-encoding them to various formats. Is this correct? This can be done in fewer steps. Some of your options are conflicting (`-r 10` and `-r 30`), and you should show your complete ffmpeg console output for at least one of these commands (but preferably all of them in an easy to read layout).

Comment: ...and what is "Player"?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The player is JW Player version 6

Comment: @LordNeckbeard All steps that you mention is correct: Cut the video, adding image, concatenate videos and re-encoding.
And put the output of my commands on console in pastebin.

Comment: Will all inputs be the same format and frame size? Do you really require an absolute size of 476x268? Why change the frame rate?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Yes, all my videos have the same format and frame size.
It's require 476x268.
About the option `-r 10` and `-r 30` .. I removed `-r 10`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard this is the output for cut video: http://pastebin.com/W0BD4bsF

Comment: @LordNeckbeard this is the ouput of add image watermark a one of this parts of the video: http://pastebin.com/NixNWC35

Comment: @LordNeckbeard this is the ouput of my mencoder command: http://pastebin.com/adzLLt9z

Comment: @LordNeckbeard This is the output of the command that convert to flv format: http://pastebin.com/MUYpH3Np

Comment: @LordNeckbeard this is the output to re-encoder the mp4 (mencoder) to mp4 format using ffmpeg: http://pastebin.com/Mm7HDErt

Comment: @LordNeckbeard the final output of convert mp4 to webm: http://pastebin.com/BrV43dBt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24469/discussion-between-lordneckbeard-and-user6964)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Make segments and overlay image

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -i image.jpg -ss 30 -t 5 -c:v libx264 -preset medium \
-crf 23 -filter_complex overlay=308:43 -c:a libfaac -q:a 100 output1.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.flv -i image.jpg -ss 60 -t 5 -c:v libx264 -preset medium \
-crf 23 -filter_complex overlay=308:43 -c:a libfaac -q:a 100 output2.mp4
```

#### Concatenate the segments and encode

First make the file list that the demuxer will read from. It is named `list.txt` in this example:

```
echo "file 'output1.mp4'" >> list.txt
echo "file 'output2.mp4'" >> list.txt
```

The contents of `list.txt` are simply:

```
file 'output1.mp4'
file 'output2.mp4'
```

Now concatenate the videos `output1.mp4` and `output2.mp4` using the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat). The demuxer will use the files listed in `list.txt` as inputs:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -movflags faststart final.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c:v libvpx -c:a libtheora -q:a 3 final.webm
```

The `-movflags faststart` will allow the mp4 file to begin playback in JW Player before it is completely downloaded. You will want to add some sort of rate control method to the webm example (such as `-b:v`). I am unfamiliar with this encoder and the defaults are not great.

Now you have a file with H.264 video and AAC audio in MP4 container, and a file with VP8 video and Vorbis audio in webm container which should provide decent coverage for the various browsers.

#### See also

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)
- [How to concatenate (join, merge) media files](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files#demuxer)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You do more simply the process!